# Do we want the mhchem extension?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

There is [an mhchem extension](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26/enable-mhchem-mathjax-extension) for Mathjax that could prove useful in some cases. Would it help on Worldbuilding? I've seen questions involving chemical reactions that might find it pretty helpful.

I've asked about the possible downsides on [Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261021/are-there-any-downsides-to-using-mhchem).

Comment: What is the drawback ?

Comment: @bilbo_pingouin I have no idea if there is a technical drawback.

Comment: If there aren't, I don't see why we don't have it already ;-)

Comment: As long as it's not mandatory to use these extensions and that there are no drawbacks = yes.

Comment: Do any other sites (like Chemistry) already use it?  Or is this something that would have to be newly implemented on the network?

Comment: @MonicaCellio Chemistry already uses it.

Answer (score 4):

I'd say we do. As long as someone can provide a link to some basic documentation on how to use it, I see it being very useful. I know for a fact there have been several answers of mine alone that could have done with better chemical equation formatting, and plenty more questions that could have had chemically-minded answers for which it would be useful.

Of course, there may be technical limitations we don't know of; that's for SE to tell us about.